Existence and Uniqueness of MLE for a collection of Bernoulli Random Variables
Suppose $Y_1\cdots Y_{10}$ are independent Bernoulli-$\frac{\exp(\alpha+x_i\beta)}{1+\exp(\alpha+x_i\beta)}$ random variables. $x_1\cdots x_{10}$ are fixed and known, $x_1\neq0$, $x$ is not a scalar multiple of the all one vector. $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the unknown parameters I am trying to estimate. Suppose $Y_1$=1 and $Y_i=0$, $\forall i\geq2$, I want to show that the MLE for $(\alpha, \beta)$ exist and is unique. So far here is where I got: (everything is done for this specific choice of $Y$, for convenience I write $(\alpha,\beta)=\theta$).

I computed the log likelihood and partial derivatives, and showed that the log likelihood is convex:
$$p(Y,\theta) = \exp(\alpha+x_1\beta)(\prod_{i=1}^{10}(1+\exp(\alpha+x_i\beta)))^{-1}$$
$$\log p(Y,\theta) = \alpha+x_1\beta-\sum_{i=1}^{10}\log(1+\exp(\alpha+x_i\beta))$$
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \alpha}\log p(Y,\theta) = 1-\sum_{i=1}^{10}\frac{\exp(\alpha+x_i\beta)}{1+\exp(\alpha+x_i\beta)}$$
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta}\log p(Y,\theta) = x_i-\sum_{i=1}^{10}\frac{x_i\exp(\alpha+x_i\beta)}{1+\exp(\alpha+x_i\beta)}$$
$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial^2 \alpha}\log p(Y,\theta) = -\sum_{i=1}^{10}\frac{\exp(\alpha+x_i\beta)}{(1+\exp(\alpha+x_i\beta))^2}$$
$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \alpha\partial\beta}\log p(Y,\theta) = -\sum_{i=1}^{10}\frac{x_i\exp(\alpha+x_i\beta)}{(1+\exp(\alpha+x_i\beta))^2}$$
$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \alpha\partial\beta}\log p(Y,\theta) = -\sum_{i=1}^{10}\frac{x_i^2\exp(\alpha+x_i\beta)}{(1+\exp(\alpha+x_i\beta))^2}$$
$$det(D^2 log p(Y,\theta))=(\sum v_i)(\sum u_i^2/vi)-(\sum u_i)^2\geq0$$
the last inequality is Titu's Lemma, with the suitable $u_i$ and $v_i$.
Then I tried to immitate a proof I have seen in class, taking
$$(\alpha_r, \beta_r)=argmin_{(\alpha,\beta)\in B(0,r0)} {\log p(Y,\theta)}$$
Now if
$$\lim_{r\to\infty} \|(\alpha_r,\beta_r)\|<\infty$$
we would be done. My plan with the $\|(\alpha_r,\beta_r)\|\to\infty$ as $r\to\infty$ case is to somehow show that the gradient at some $(\alpha_r,\beta_r)$ would be zero, a contradiction, or that the log likelihood tends to $-\infty$ along this trajectory. (I think this is not possible, since there is nothing wrong with $\alpha_r+x_1\beta_r\to\infty$, $\alpha_r+x_i\beta_r\to-\infty$ for all other $i$. This would make the log likelihood go to 0) Thanks in advance for your help.


You don't need to compute any derivatives to show the existence and uniqueness of the optimum; instead, a much simpler strategy is to show that $\log p(Y, \theta)$ is strictly concave, which implies both the existence and the uniqueness of the global maximum. To show this, you need to put together the following standard observations:

A sum of concave functions is concave, and any linear function is concave. Thus, you need to show that all the $-\log (1 + \exp(\alpha + \beta x_j) )$ terms are concave for $1 \le j \le 10$, and one of them is strictly concave.
A negation of a (strictly) convex function is a (strictly) concave function. Thus, you now have to show that the $\log (1 + \exp(\alpha + \beta x_j) )$ terms are convex.
If $f(x)$ is a convex function, then $f(ax+b)$ is also a convex function; if you also have $a \neq 0$ and a strictly convex $f$, then $f(ax+b)$ is a strictly convex function. After applying this to each summand, you need to show that $\log(1+e^t)$ is strictly convex to complete the proof.
$\frac{d^2 \log(1+e^t)}{dt^2} = \frac{e^t}{(1+e^t)^2}>0$, which implies the strict convexity of $\log(1+e^t)$.

